# Нецелое число пикселей при верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, табличная-верстка

Как задать размер элемента при написании html-кода в нецелое число пикселей, а именно в целое число и бесконечную десятичную дробь (например, (100/3)%)?

Comment: `33.3%`, `33.33%`, `33.333%`, `33.3333%`... и так далее

Comment: `.element { width: calc(100% / 3); }`

Comment: width: calc(100%/3);

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта:

1. Сами считаете на калькуляторе и записываете результат `width: 33.3333%;`(четырёх знаков после запятой вполне хватит)
2. Используете функцию `width: calc(100%/3);`.